# Generating a carousel slider

Tags: javascript, performance, event-handling, backbone.js

I'm currently using Backbone to generate a carousel slider.  In my `View`, I have an `initialize` function that looks like this:

```
var SlideModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    defaults: {
        id: null,
        source_url: null,
        date: null,
        slug: null,
        link: null
    },
    idAttribute: '_id'
});

var SlideCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SlideModel,
    url: 'https://www.usarugby.org/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=Club',
    parse: function(response){
        return response;
    }
});

var SlideView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#hero-wrapper',
    className: 'carousel-cell',
    template: _.template( $('#tmpl-hero-slides').html() ),
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'update', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'update', this.afterRender);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'update', this.scaleSlider);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'update', this.correctDate);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            slides: this.collection.toJSON()
        }));
        return this;
    },
    afterRender: function() {
        var $carousel = $('#hero'),
            $win = $(window);

        $carousel.royalSlider({
            autoScaleSlider: !0,
            autoScaleSliderWidth: 1125,
            autoScaleSliderHeight: 593,
            controlNavigation: 'bullets',
            arrowsNav: !0,
            imageScaleMode: 'fill',
            imageAlignCenter: !0,
            numImagesToPreload: 5,
            sliderTouch: !0,
            autoplay: {
                enabled: !0,
                pauseOnHover: !0,
                delay: 4000
            },
            loop: !0,
            transitionType: rs.fadeOrMove(),
            navigateByClick: !0,
            allowCSS3: rs.cssOnDesk(),
            addActiveClass: !0
        });

        $carousel.removeClass('hide');

    },
    scaleSlider: function(){
        $('.royalSlider').royalSlider('updateSliderSize', true);
    },
    correctDate: function(){
        $('.royalSlider .rsSlide').each(function(){
            var str = $(this).find('.date').html(),
                slideDate = new Date( str );
            $(this).find('.date').html( slideDate.toDateString() );
        });
    }
});

var slidecollection = new SlideCollection(),
    slideshow = new SlideView({ collection: slidecollection });
slidecollection.fetch();
slideshow.render();
```

Is this the most efficient way to write the `initialize` function with each listener listening for the same event one after the other, or is there a better way to write the function?

I've added the entire `Backbone` script for my carousel. [`RoyalSlider`](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider) is a third-party plugin that powers the carousel.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  You may get better feedback if you provide more context.  For example, at the moment it's unclear why you are listening four times.  I'm guessing that would be clearer if we saw more of your application.  What if the solution would be to move these lines out of this function and into another portion of your app?  We couldn't make explicit suggestions about that without the code for the places where we might move these lines.

Comment: I've added the entire script.  Please let me know if more context is needed.